# enciphering function is not outputing string as it should

Tags: string, inputstream, outputstream

This function takes in a string as an argument and then enciphers the numbers and should write an enciphered string to a file. eText in the main seems to not be getting anything from the function and I cannot figure out why.

Function Definition:

```
string Encipherer::encipherer(string plainMessage){

    int i = plainMessage.length();
    string eMessage;

    cout << i << endl;

    for(i = 0; i >= plainMessage.length(); i++){
            if(plainMessage[i] >= 65 && plainMessage[i] <= 90){
                    if(plainMessage[i] + shift > 90){
                            eMessage[i] += plainMessage[i] - 26 + shift;
                    }

                    else{
                            eMessage += plainMessage[i] + shift;
                    }
            }

            else if(plainMessage[i] >= 97 && plainMessage[i] <= 122){
                    if(plainMessage[i] + shift > 122){
                            eMessage[i] += plainMessage[i] - 26 + shift;
                    }
                    else{
                            eMessage += plainMessage[i] + shift;
                    }
            }
}

            else{
                    eMessage += plainMessage[i];
            }

}
return eMessage;
}
```

Main Function:

```
int main(){

string plainMessage, eText;
string fileName = "inputText.txt";
ofstream outputText;
        outputText.open ("outputText.txt");

Encipherer E(5);

plainMessage = E.encipherFromFile(fileName);

eText = E.encipherer(plainMessage);

outputText << eText;

outputText.close();


return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Encipherer::encipherer`

```
for(i = 0; i >= plainMessage.length(); i++){
```

should be

```
for(i = 0; i < plainMessage.length(); i++){
```

Also, in both if blocks:

```
                    eMessage[i] += plainMessage[i] - 26 + shift;
```

should become

```
                    eMessage += plainMessage[i] - 26 + shift;
```

Is `shift` defined on some other place? And you seem to have a `}` before the last `else` that shouldn't be there, if the code is copied correctly.